# Using Crittercism in Cordova android application

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, crittercism

We are trying to include Crittercism in our Cordova android application.

We are using the app in the path https://github.com/crittercism/PhoneGapExampleApp. But we are seeing only the number of applications installed in live stats not the crash report. Even when the application is crashing we are not getting logs in the console. Please help us to include Crittercism in Cordova app and get the crash report.

Note: We got alerts when the application crashed. But we wanted to use free version of Crittercism as we need only crash logs.

Can we use Crittercism for JavaScript crashes or crashes due to JavaScript memory issues?

Answer (score 6):

I currently work with Apteligent (formerly called Crittercism) so I can provide some insight on what you're seeing with the Cordova app.

Unhandled JavaScript errors tend to come in as Handled Exceptions because the app itself generally doesn't crash, which at the time was not available on Basic/Standard. Handled Exceptions are now available on the Standard tier so if you're still using us on Standard, you should be able to see them under Handled Exceptions on the left.

If you want to report JavaScript errors as a crash instead of a Handled Exception, you can use the setLogUnhandledExceptionAsCrash API:

```js
Crittercism.setLogUnhandledExceptionAsCrash(value);
Crittercism.getLogUnhandledExceptionAsCrash();
```

The value should be a boolean. An example on how to use setLogUnhandledExceptionAsCrash:

```js
function callCriticalBusinessFunction() {
    try {
        setLogUnhandledExceptionAsCrash(true);
        criticalBusinessFunction();
    } finally {
        setLogUnhandledExceptionAsCrash(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's more info from the docs: https://docs.apteligent.com/development_platforms/phonegap.html#logging-crashes https://docs.apteligent.com/development_platforms/phonegap.html#logging-handled-exceptions